# git pull causes OpenSSH prompt

Tags: git, https, openssh

I haven't changed my Windows AD password, but I'm suddenly getting prompted when performing `git` commands, like `git pull`.

[image]

I've tried various things, like changing my .gitconfig to use HTTPS instead of SSH (git). I also updated my Windows Credential Manager to make sure it was using the correct AD password.

Someone suggested I abandon SSH and use HTTPS instead. I'm struggling to figure out how to do that. No matter what I do, I keep getting the OpenSSH dialog. How can I change to HTTPS, or stop that dialog from coming up with every `git` command?

If it helps, here is my .gitconfig (with the diff and merge options removed):

```
[user]
    name = myuser
    email = myuser@xxx.com
[push]
    default = simple
[credential]
    helper = wincred
```

Source: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows-Popups/qaq-p/579905

Comment: Did you add a passphrase to the ssh key when you created it?

Comment: I honestly don't remember.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this command worked for me:

```
git config --global credential.useHttpPath true
```

That caused the last line here to be in the .gitconfig file:

```
[credential]
    helper = wincred
    useHttpPath = true
```

The first time I did a `git pull`, I got the prompt again. But after that I'm no longer getting the login dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. you just need to install GCM
https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/releases/tag/v2.0.475